# Trying to make sense of "this" in my javascript code (one thing works, the other doesn't)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to learn javascript by refactoring some Jquery examples in a book into javascript. In the following code I add a click listener to a tab and make it change to active when the user clicks on the tab.

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs a span");
var content = document.querySelectorAll("main .content li");

for (var tabNumber = 0; tabNumber <= 2; tabNumber++) {
  tabs[tabNumber].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      tabs[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    tabs[tabNumber].classList.add("active");
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      content[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

This returns an `undefined error` when I run it. However, I tried replacing `tabs[tabNumber].classList.add("active")` with `this.classList.add("active")` and it worked.

Why doesn't the previous code work? As far as I can see they are referring to the same thing, and `tabs[tabNumber]` should work since at that point in the code it is `tabs[0]`.

Comment: If you console.log(tabNumber) within your event handler you'll find it is 3, no matter which item you clicked.

Comment: use `let` for for loops as much as possible, but the issue can be resolved by closure or the place you reference it in your JS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess other answers told you why `tabs[tabNumber]` does not work (because it comes from the score of the for loop and so, is always equal to the greater value of tabNumber).

That's why I would recommend using a `.forEach` loop. Careful though because it doesn't work on arrays of DOM nodes produced by `document.querySelectorAll()`, but you can use:

```
// ES6
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('...'))
// ES5
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('...'))
```

Anyway, I made a simplified **[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5zhejbne/)** of your code.
Note that I save the currently active tab in a variable, to prevent another `for` loop. You could also do:

```
document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
```

But I like to reduce the amount of DOM reading.

Good luck for your apprentissage, re-writing some jQuery code into Vanilla JS seems like a good method, and you might acquire a far better comprehension of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

If use `this`, I think it's better and a more polished solution. If you still want to use `tabNumber`, it's probably evaluating to `3` in every click callback, because it's the number after the last iteration, and you don't have a `tabs[3]` position.

So, you just have to make a closure of the `tabNumber` variable.